# python cgi script always got 403 forbidden with apache2 2.4.6

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, curl

work environment: Ubuntu 13.10 saucy, apache2 2.4.6

I have a python script in /usr/lib/cgi-bin and I use it as a proxy for convert internal url to external. it works great with apache 2.2 but always got 403 forbidden error.

```
/etc/apache2/site-enabled/mirror.conf

ScriptAlias /mirror /usr/lib/cgi-bin/mirror.py

/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mirror.py
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import pycurl

username = "username"
password = "password"
base = "https://mirror.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx"

if os.environ.has_key(‘PATH_INFO’):
    path = os.environ[‘PATH_INFO’]
else:
    path = ‘/’

dst = base + path

def write(data):
    sys.stdout.write(data)

def header(data):
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('HTTP/'):
            ret = line.split()[1]
            sys.stdout.write('Status: ' + ret + '\r\n')
        elif line.startswith('Location:'):
            line = line.replace('https://mirror.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx', 'http://mirror.internal/mirror')
            sys.stdout.write(line + '\r\n')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line + '\r\n')

curl = pycurl.Curl()

curl.setopt(curl.URL, dst)

curl.setopt(curl.HEADERFUNCTION, header)
curl.setopt(curl.USERPWD, '%s:%s' % (username, password))
curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, write)

curl.perform()
curl.close()
```

any tips for apache new version I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apach2 2.4.6 don't put cgid.conf and cgid.load in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled as default. after make soft link from mods-available to mods-enabled, the issue be fixed.